# Embed YouTube Video in PowerPoint with Spire.Presentation

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, powerpoint

I'm using Spire.Presentation to create PowerPoint presentations using .NET.

Inserting a locally saved video works perfectly like this:

```
public static void SetVideoMedia(this ISlide slide, int index, string pathToVideo)
{
    var shape = slide.Shapes[index];
    var rect = new RectangleF(shape.Left, shape.Top, shape.Width, shape.Height);

    slide.Shapes.AppendVideoMedia(pathToVideo, rect, true);
    slide.Shapes.Remove(shape);
}
```

But I can't find out how to insert a YouTube video and I can't find anything in the guides...

The only thing I've found is this site with some sort of markup:
https://sourceforge.net/p/spirepresentation/discussion/markdown_syntax#md_ex_video.

But I don't know how to use that in the code. Does anyone know how to embed a YouTube video?

Comment: The only handicap I see is getting the youtube video. If you get the html for a youtube video page and look for usual video related keywords like `mp4` you will not find a easy way to download programatically the video, thats why pepole usually do use browser plugins to download the videos. I have just seen that with VLC you can do the download so, if that feature were based on some sort of standar streaming protocol, you could get profit of that and implement it in your code. Worth checking it. Or call VLC command line programatically to get the same download.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing true to false. False - since the link targets a directory outside its parent directory.

`AppendVideoMedia(URL, rectangle, false);`

Link: https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/how-are-videos-are-embedded-t6050.html